# ListView_GetItemText only gets first character

Tags: c++, winapi, listview

I am trying to get the text value of a ListView sub-item by using [`ListView_GetItemText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Here is my code:

```
char *bufText = new char[256];
ListView_GetItemText(GetDlgItem(myWindow, MYLISTVIEW), myInt, 1, (LPTSTR)bufText, 256);
```

`myInt` is the index of a line in list-view.

But `strlen(bufText)` is equal to 1, and the only character in `bufText` is the first one of the list-view sub-item.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have got the standard outcome when you suppress a compiler error with a cast. When the compiler told you that `bufText` was the wrong type, you chose the wrong solution. Instead of declaring it correctly, you just told the compiler that you knew better than it and cast. Remove that cast and fix the problem properly.

Comment: Then, could you explain how to fix it properly?

Comment: Jonathan's answer already does that. You really don't want to use the ANSI API. That went out with Windows ME. I've no idea why you think that sending `LVM_GETITEMTEXTA` is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is my code:
>
> ```
> char *bufText = new char[256];
> ListView_GetItemText(GetDlgItem(myWindow, MYLISTVIEW), myInt, 1, (LPTSTR)bufText, 256);
> ```
>
> But `strlen(bufText)` is equal to 1, and the only character in
>   `bufText` is the first one of the list-view sub-item.
>
> What am I doing wrong here?

I think the problem is that you are **building in Unicode mode** (which has been the default since VS2005), so `ListView_GetItemText()` was sending you a Unicode string, but you have a **mismatch**, since the type of `bufText` is `char*` (i.e. ANSI/MBCS string), not `wchar_t*` (i.e. Unicode UTF-16 string).

The compiler was *helping you*, giving you an error message, since you were passing a pointer to an ANSI/MBCS string (the `char* bufText` argument) instead of `wchar_t*`.
But instead of trying to *listening to the compiler*, you shut it up with the wrong type cast to `LPTSTR` (which in Unicode builds is expanded to `wchar_t*`).

---

So, why did you get just **one character**?

Suppose that the text stored in the list-view control (to be retrieved by `ListView_GetItemText()`) is `"hello"`.

It's Unicode representation in memory is:

```
68 00   65 00   6C 00   6C 00   6F 00   00 00
  h       e       l        l      o      NUL
```

(since Unicode UTF-16 representation for `h` is `0x0068`, for `e` is `0x0065`, for `l` is `0x006C`, for `o` is `0x006F`; `0x0000` is the Unicode `NUL` terminator.)

But when you *interpret* the above *byte sequence* as *ANSI string*, the (single byte) `NUL` terminator for an ANSI string is the *first* `0x00` byte after the `0x68` (ASCII `h`) byte, so in ANSI you just get:

```
68  00      <---- ANSI stops at the *first* 0x00 byte
 h  \0
```

i.e. the `"h"` ANSI string, so you just get the *first character* of the initial Unicode UTF-16 string.

---

My advice is to just move to **Unicode builds in modern software**.

Moreover, those *raw C-like arrays* of characters are not modern C++: they are not exception-safe, moreover you have to pay attention to *manually* `delete[]` the returned pointer, etc.
It's better to **use a modern robust RAII container**, like `std::vector` or `std::wstring`.

e.g.

```
#include <vector> // for std::vector

....
//
// Allocate a vector of 256 wchar_t's (so use Unicode).
//
// (Note: Memory is automatically cleaned up in the destructor,
// no need for *manual* delete[].)
//
std::vector<wchar_t> bufText( 256 );

//
// Get text from the list-view control.
//
ListView_GetItemText
(
    GetDlgItem(myWindow, MYLISTVIEW), 
    myInt, 
    1, 
    &bufText[0],    // <--- pointer to first character in the buffer
    bufText.size()  // <--- size of the buffer, in wchar_t's
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Unicode build but passing (with a cast) an ANSI buffer to the control. Change from:

```
char* bufText = new char[256];
```

to:

```
wchar_t* bufText = new wchar_t[256];
```

(Or, if you specifically want to use ANSI, send the `LVM_GETITEMTEXTA` message rather than using the macro).

Comment: Well, I am also suspecting an encoding mistake. I already tried to use a `wchar_t` but there is still the same issue :(